# https redirect with express-sslify

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

My web app runs on node.js and express server.

```
const port = process.env.PORT
server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("server is running on port", port);
});

app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true }));
```

and I have another sendFile routing file:

```
const Router = require('express').Router;
const router = new Router();
var path = require('path');

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/html/main/pllanet.html"));
});
```

When I push the app live on Heroku, the url redirect goes as the following:

1) domain.com   =>    https://www.example.com

2) www.example.com    =>     www.example.com

3) http://www.example.com  =>    https://www.example.com

All urls redirects fine to the https one, except when I type www.example.com in my address bar. What I did wrong here?

Thanks in advance.